# Bound on the difference between BFGS approx-Hessian and the exact Hessian

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given a strongly convex function $f(x)$ with Lipschitz continuous gradient and Lipschitz Hessian, i.e.,

$$\mu I \leq \nabla ^2 f(x)\leq LI,\quad ||\nabla^2f(x)-\nabla f^2(y)||\leq M||x-y||^2,$$

and if we use the BFGS to approximate the curvature information, i.e.,
$$B_{t+1} = B_t+\frac{y_ty_t^\top}{y_t^\top s_t}-\frac{B_ts_ts_t^\top B_t}{s_t^\top B_ts_t},$$

where $y_t=\nabla f_{t+1}-\nabla f_t$ and $s_t=x_{t+1}-x_t$, can we bound the difference between $B_t$ and $\nabla^2 f_t$ other than the triangle inequality ? It seems a intuitive question to ask but I couldn't find anything on this.
$$||B_t-\nabla^2 f_t||\leq \,\,??$$
You can also assume $\gamma I\leq B_t\leq \Gamma I$ if that helps. Feel free to put on more "meaningful" assumptions.

Comment: how do you update $x_t$ ?

Comment: Assuming I am updating as $x_{t+1}=x_t-\epsilon_t B_t^{-1}\nabla f(x_t)$ where the step size is determined by some line search methods.